# Error on Sending mail asp.net via console applications

Tags: asp.net

I am have written a test console application for retrieving the data and sending mail from the message queue.My console application resides in the same
solution of my main project.In my message queue lies the mail messages.When i run my console application there is a call to
the mail sending method but the problem is mail is not getting sent.seenms that  mailSettings that i have given in
web.config file is not getting  applied when i am sending mail via the console applications.Because when i am sending mail directly without
the help of console application the message is getting send successfully.Also when i specify the mail setting options in the
source code itself via smtp properties mail is getting send via console applications.But i want to send the mail via console application with
the mail setting set on web.congig.

How can i overcome this problem.

Best regards.

My setting in web.config.

My code for sending mails

public static void SendMailMessage(string from, string to, string bcc, string cc, string subject, string body,List attachments)
        {
            // Instantiate a new instance of MailMessage
            MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();

```
        // Set the sender address of the mail message
        mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);

        // Set the recepient address of the mail message
        //string[] arrEmailTo = to.Split(',');
        //foreach (string itemTo in arrEmailTo)
        //{

        //    //mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(itemTo));
        //}
        mMailMessage.To.Add(to);

        // Check if the bcc value is null or an empty string
        if ((bcc != null) && (bcc != string.Empty))
        {
            // Set the Bcc address of the mail message
            mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(bcc));
        }

        // Check if the cc value is null or an empty value
        if ((cc != null) && (cc != string.Empty))
        {
            // Set the CC address of the mail message
            mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(cc));
        }

        // Set the subject of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Subject = subject;

        //mMailMessage.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        //int Idd=BitConverter.ToInt32(Encrypt((Id.Id).ToString()),0);
        // byte[] IdHash = Encrypt((Id.Id).ToString());//generating hassh value
        //int IdHash1 = BitConverter.ToInt32(IdHash, 0);
        //passing the hash value by encoding it


        // Set the body of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Body = body;

        //include the attachments if any

        if(attachments!=null)

            foreach (string file in attachments)
            {
                Attachment aa = new Attachment(UpPath+file);
                mMailMessage.Attachments.Add(aa);
            }

        // Secify the format of the body as HTML
        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
        SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        mSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
```

//*********
   //With these options set in the source code mail is getting sent fine
  //******

```
        //mSmtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        //mSmtpClient.Port = 25;
        // Send the mail message
        //System.Net.NetworkCredential s = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
        //mSmtpClient.Credentials = s;
        //mSmtpClient.Port = 587;
        mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
```

//*********
   //With these options set in the source code mail is getting sent fine
  //******
        }

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for your testing, add an App.Config to the Console project with your mail settings.